# Find time difference in hours and minutes between datetime stamps formatted as YYYY-MM-DDTHH-MM-SS.sssZ in SQLite or Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a series of datetime stamps that I need to find the difference of in hours. The problem is getting it to account for the day differences when applicable. I can either try to do it in Python when the data is added to the dataframes or in SQL when I'm analyzing the data. Either way works.

SQL code I'm using to test:

```
SELECT commentId, commentStamp, replyStamp, 
       strftime('%H:%M:%SZ',(julianday(replyStamp) - julianday(commentStamp))) 
FROM time_table
```

Output:

```
('AAAAA00000',
  '2020-11-10T13:26:10.162Z',
  '2020-11-10T13:35:37.292Z',
  '12:09:27Z'),
 ('AAAAA11111',
  '2020-11-09T18:48:03.073Z',
  '2020-11-10T13:08:22.813Z',
  '06:20:19Z'),
```

Expected result would be something like this, just need hours and minutes:

```
('AAAAA00000',
  '2020-11-10T13:26:10.162Z',
  '2020-11-10T13:35:37.292Z',
  '00:09'),
 ('AAAAA11111',
  '2020-11-09T18:48:03.073Z',
  '2020-11-10T13:08:22.813Z',
  '18:40'),
```

I can't really find anything that works. Everything I've tried does not calculate the differences correctly.

Comment: Post your expected results.

Comment: Added an expected result. Just need hours and minutes between the first and second timestamp for each section

Comment: The 2nd difference should be 18:20 and not 19:40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Date And Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> The julianday() function returns the Julian day - the number of days
> since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. (Proleptic Gregorian
> calendar).

so, the difference in your query is a difference in days and must be multiplied by `24 * 60 * 60` to get the difference in seconds and use it with `strftime()` to format it as time (with `'unixepoch'` modifier):

```
SELECT commentId, commentStamp, replyStamp, 
       strftime('%H:%M', (julianday(replyStamp) - julianday(commentStamp)) * 24 *60 * 60, 'unixepoch') diff
FROM time_table
```

Or with `strftime('%s', ...)` which returns the number of seconds since 1970-01-01:

```
SELECT commentId, commentStamp, replyStamp, 
       strftime('%H:%M', strftime('%s', replyStamp) - strftime('%s', commentStamp), 'unixepoch') diff
FROM time_table
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=541af03ea886803d8860fa669a9ab5fb).
Results:

```
> commentId  | commentStamp             | replyStamp               | diff 
> :--------- | :----------------------- | :----------------------- | :----
> AAAAA00000 | 2020-11-10T13:26:10.162Z | 2020-11-10T13:35:37.292Z | 00:09
> AAAAA11111 | 2020-11-09T18:48:03.073Z | 2020-11-10T13:08:22.813Z | 18:20
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. Datetime stamps have always been really confrusing for me.